# Web development with python and sql

Tags: python

I need to build a web site with the following features:
1) user forum where we expect light daily traffic
2) database backend for users to create profiles, where they can log in
and upload media (pictures)
3) users can uses their profile to buy content from an online inventory
4) create web pages, shopping carts etc for online inventory
5) secure online credit card processing

I am very familiar with python but not with python web frameworks. I do know
some SQL. How do I get started developing something like this? Is Django
a good alternative?

Not programming related per se: Where do you recommend I get web hosting with a domain
name for an application like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) was made for this kind of thing. Check it out.

As far as hosting, [djangofriendly.com](http://www.djangofriendly.com) is a great resource. I have used [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/?affiliate=paolob) before and I am absolutely in love with how easy it is to get Django going with them and with their excellent customer service. Very top notch for reasonable prices if you are going the shared hosting route.

If you are looking to speed up some of the tasks described, you should check out [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) and [Django Pluggables](http://djangoplugables.com/). Thanks to the way Django applications are setup it is trivially easy to plug an application into your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Pylons](http://www.pylonshq.com/) lightweight web framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements make [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) sound like a library you might want to look into if you go the django route.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine will provide hosting for free as well as Django and a db..